# Remove border color from linear gradient

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, linear-gradients

I've a problem removing a (border) color from a overlapping linear gradient. In IE 11 it workes as expected. In Firefox there is a small visible grey line between the gradients. How can I remove this?

[image: arrow shows the problem]

I tried it this way:

```
.box2 {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(154deg, red 67%, transparent 33%), -webkit-linear-gradient(26deg, transparent 67%, red 33%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(154deg, red 67%, transparent 33%), -moz-linear-gradient(26deg, transparent 67%, red 33%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(154deg, red 67%, transparent 33%), -ms-linear-gradient(26deg, transparent 67%, red 33%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(154deg, red 67%, transparent 33%), -o-linear-gradient(26deg, transparent 67%, red 33%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(154deg, red 67%, transparent 33%), linear-gradient(26deg, transparent 67%, red 33%);
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80% 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aam6roaf/

Comment: In my FF I can not see it (FF 45.0.2)

Comment: Dmitry: very strange. I use the same FF-Version, but I still see the "border" or whatever it is... what OS do you use? Linux? WIN? Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the very same issue in Firefox v45.0.2 or Windows 10. While I have no idea why that line is appearing, it goes away when I set the color-stop points like in the below snippet. Setting color stops like in the below snippet also has the advantage of producing smoother angled gradients.

This works well in Firefox v45.0.2, Chrome(v51.0.2704.19 dev-m), Opera v36, IE11 and Edge.

```css
.box2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(154deg, red 67%, transparent 67.25%), linear-gradient(26deg, transparent 67%, red 67.25%);
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80% 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Comment: Well, it works! The solution seems to be, that the second value (my 33%) must be greater than the frist value. I confirmed it with some test values.

Comment: Yep @Marco. It must always be greater because it is essentially color-stop/start points (and not fill percentages), so the second color should start from the point where the first ends (or later) but even with 67.1% as value, there is a tiny visible border lines in FF which is not seen in any other browser. So, it probably needs to be 67% + a delta.